# Rails - show item price and add to total price

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a form where it displays the items in a select2 drop down box but I would like to also display the price for the item and enter a quantity amount that will show the total price. It would be nice to use select2 gem with these added features but I am not sure how to do this.

I have to know which item is selected and then pull the price from the table for it.

## Form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :code %>    

    <%= f.association :items, collection: Item.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose an item", input_html: { id: 'item-select2' } %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

## Talbe

```
  create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.decimal  "discount"
  end
  create_table "orders", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "code"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
  create_table "order_items", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.decimal  "price"
  end
```

Comment: You project is private? Or i can found it on github?

Comment: It's hard to understand how it should look like with select2. Is it multiselect?

Comment: yes multiselect, drop down select box with a search

Comment: even without the select2, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use AJAX. 
Let say we have a form (*order*) where we have a table (*order_items*). We will add rows with some goodies (*items*), their price and quantity. Let assume that an user already opened new order and added a new row. In the row we put the select with items, span **price** and text field **quantity**. Under table we have span **total**

1. User selects item. When item is selected we call 'on_change' javascript event for this select.
2. Inside that call we sent AJAX request to items controller (method 'show') with id of selected item. Inside the controller#show we find our item and return it to client as json.
3. On client we have an javasript object *item*. Using javascript we place *item.price* inside span **price**.
4. Another 'on_change' we must call for quantity text field. When quantity changed we iterate all rows, calc sum for each row and accumalate it in result vatiable. Then we put this result in **total** span.

Comment: Something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/slav123/75m7e/3/) integrated with the form?

Comment: Yes, you can get it without Angular, jQuery is enough here.

Comment: how would I send an AJAX request to items controller (method show) with id selected (basically do #2)

Comment: app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

    $('#select_with_goodies').on('change', function(){
      $.get('items_controller/' + $('#select_with_goodies').val());
    });

app/views/items/show.js

  // update form based on received data